# basic java programming (naming a file)

Tags: java

i got a run-time error on executing a file 'complement.java' that read

D:\java\files\java complement
 Error:Could not find or load main class complement

the class structure follows as below

```
import java.io.*;
class billion  
{  
 .  
 .  
 .  
 //class definition  
}
```

what could be the cause for the prompt mentioned above?

Comment: Did you use a search engine to research the error message?

Comment: Hint: read a good tutorial; instead of expecting us to the super basics to you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Comment: problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this question can be easily answered by 5 seconds of quick googling, supposing you dont know java.

Anyway, the error only shows when your main class is missing a main method, which start the whole program. The main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

Add this to your main class, and start it again.

Answer (score 2):

File name and class name need to be same. And the class you mention in `java` command should have a `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```